# PDFKit causing incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, character-encoding, pdfkit

I am trying to use the PDFkit gem in rails to generate a pdf of a specific div. I am getting this error:

```
incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

It occurs when I add this into my view:

```
<%= render :text => PDFKit.new("<p>Hello World<p>".force_encoding("UTF-8")).to_pdf %>
```

I also added this to the head of my Application.html.erb

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I am trying to enforce the encoding to UTF-8. Am I doing something wrong? Has anybody found a solution to this?

Initializer (pdfkit.rb):

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = `which wkhtmltopdf`.to_s.strip
  config.default_options = {
      :encoding=>"UTF-8",
      :page_size=>"A4",
      :margin_top=>"0.25in",
      :margin_right=>"1in",
      :margin_bottom=>"0.25in",
      :margin_left=>"1in",
      :disable_smart_shrinking=>false
  }
end
```

Full Backtrace:

```
Started GET "/
player_orders/16" for ::1 at 2015-08-02 15:58:44 -0400
Processing by 
playerOrdersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"16"}

playerOrder Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "
player_orders".* FROM "
player_orders" WHERE "
player_orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 16]]

player Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "
players".* FROM "
players" WHERE "
players"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Organization Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "medications" INNER JOIN "order_results" ON "medications"."id" = "order_results"."medication_id" WHERE "order_results"."
player_order_id" = ?  [["
player_order_id", 16]]
  Medication Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "medications".* FROM "medications" INNER JOIN "order_results" ON "medications"."id" = "order_results"."medication_id" WHERE "order_results"."
player_order_id" = ?  [["
player_order_id", 16]]
  Rendered 
player_orders/_barcode.html.erb (0.2ms)
Loading pages (1/5)
Resolving links (2/5)                                              
Counting pages (3/5)                                                      
Printing pages (5/5)                                                      
Done                                                                      
  Rendered text template (0.1ms)
  Rendered 
player_orders/_barcode.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered text template (0.1ms)
  Rendered 
player_orders/show.html.erb within layouts/application (808.0ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_left_sidebar.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (7.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 907ms

Encoding::CompatibilityError - incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8:
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:181:in `concat'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/buffers.rb:12:in `<<'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:20:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2277723797874510784_70274889105440'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/AkashMagoon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  wicked_pdf (0.11.0) lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:23:in `render_with_wicked_pdf'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/AkashMagoon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/AkashMagoon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/AkashMagoon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Do you have `PDFKit.configure` block somewhere in your initializers? If yes, please provide us with it.

Comment: @EugZol Thanks for the response. Updated above!

Comment: Great! Now please add full backtrace, probably using [gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: Backtrace added above @EugZol

Comment: Added advice as an answer